# How can I use a letter from a font that is embedded (subset embedding but the letter is present in the document) in a PDF using Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, adobe-acrobat, embedded-fonts

How can I use a letter from a font that is embedded (subset embedding but the letter is present in the document) in a PDF using Adobe Acrobat when editing the text?

Example PDF: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P17-1175.pdf  ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20200504012232/https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P17-1175.pdf) , [mirror 2](https://archive.vn/kQio0))

When I try to edit the text, Adobe Acrobat says the original font isn't available or can't be used for editing:

[image]

[image]

I use Adobe Acrobat DC version 20.6.20042.371103 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible.

Quoting Anthony Atkielski on https://qr.ae/pNyXpu:

> Last I looked into this, you couldn’t. Font licensing for font embedding is often predicated upon it being impossible to edit the text set in the font; otherwise the license is not valid. So editing using the embedded font characters is not allowed. Additionally, PDF is intended as a final document format, not as a format that can be further edited. Changes should be made to the original source document, not the PDF.